# catalog price rules gap

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog, price, promotions, rules

I have a 10% discount rule applied on a specific category. Everything works fine, but costumers who buy between 0h00m and 1h00m dont get the discount which is annoying because they are expecting the discount…

I have search the web for this and apparently is because catalog price rules are applied on a daily base, that means they are finished @ midnight everyday and then recalculated at 1.00 am which leaves me with a gap.

After reading this article: http://www.solvingmagento.com/quick-tip-magento-catalog-price-rules-dont-work/

I have tried to change the config.xml(s) to narrow the gap.

```
<catalogrule_apply_all> 
    <schedule> 
        <cron_expr>5 0 * * *</cron_expr> 
    </schedule>
```

and

```
<catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all> 
    <schedule> 
        <cron_expr>10 0 * * *</cron_expr> 
    </schedule>
```

but i only got the rules to stop working completely… 
now, they only restart by manually apply all rules inside promotions>catalog price rules

Any ideas on how to fill this gap?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add direct call to catalog update in `cron.php` file (two lines prefixed with +):

```
try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
+    $observer = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/observer');
+    $observer->dailyCatalogUpdate("1 0 * * *");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
```